# Query Boost.Icl interval_set overlapping intervals

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to use Boost.Icl to find the size of overlapping intervals.

For example:
Given intervals [0, 20], [10, 30], [35, 40]

```
interval_set<int> iset;
iset += interval<int>::open(0, 20);
iset += interval<int>::open(10, 30);
iset += interval<int>::open(35, 40);
```

I want to query the overlapping length for the interval [20, 40] compared with those in the tree, which should be 15 (20->30 and 35->40)

I can only find a contains() function which checks if a point is inside the interval, but is there another function that does what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [equal_range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/non_mutating/equal_range.html) member function:

```
auto itRes = iset.equal_range( boost::icl::interval<int>::closed( 20, 40 ) );

for( auto it = itRes.first; it != itRes.second; ++it )
{
    std::cout << "(" << it->lower() << ", " << it->upper() << ")\n";
}
```

itRes.first is an iterator to `(20, 30)` and itRes->second an iterator to `(35, 40)`

Small sidenote: writing `[0, 20]` means a closed interval, wheras `(0, 20)` means open.